# Google api key dose not work, Get error "Oops! Something went wrong."

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-places-api, web-deployment, google-developers-console

I just implement google api key on local using wamp server for following code, this code collected form [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplet).

when i put the api key the i got error in web browser "Oops! Something went wrong.
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details."How i fix it

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APPI KEY HERE&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

Comment: You should definitely not share your api key on any public websites.

Comment: this is learning purpose, no problem i remove it

Comment: open inspector panel and add here what You see in console tab. screenshot: http://joxi.ru/1A5RRdsDnwBOrE

Comment: Have you tried including the maps script before your custom script? (I had to look at your edited post to see full code)

Comment: `See the JavaScript console for technical details` What was the error in the console? Did you make sure to enable the google maps API in your developer console before using the key?

Comment: Thank you for response, But i got the salutation, and the salutation is just activate billing account, in this way google place api will be validate